# Batch set a variable via command

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

I need to set a variable passed as a command.

for example, the command would be something like this:

```
github "Init command"
```

The command that I have to do is something like this:

```
git add. && git commit -m "/TItle" && git push origin master
```

Where `"Init command"` would be `"/Title"`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach, IMHO, would be to create a function:

```
github() {
    # $1 is the (1st) parameter passed to the function
    git add . && git commit -m "$1" && git push origin master
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering why use the function and not simply
     git add. && git commit -m "$1" && git push origin master?